# Error building 'Clp' cannot generate deps.jl in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump, clp

I am trying to install and build Clp on my system in julia but am receiving an error:

```
 Error: Error building `Clp`:
│ ERROR: LoadError: LibraryProduct(nothing, ["libClp"], :libClp, "Prefix(/global/home/users/gorman_will/.julia/packages/Clp/cX6R7/deps/usr)") is not satisfied, cannot generate deps.jl!
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] #write_deps_file#165(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}) at /global/home/users/gorman_will/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/GeAtj/src/Products.jl:419
│  [3] (::getfield(BinaryProvider, Symbol("#kw##write_deps_file")))(::NamedTuple{(:verbose,),Tuple{Bool}}, ::typeof(write_deps_file), ::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}) at ./none:0
│  [4] top-level scope at none:0
│  [5] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
│  [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [8] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
│  [9] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /global/home/users/gorman_will/.julia/packages/Clp/cX6R7/deps/build.jl:144
└ @ Pkg.Operations /global/software/sl-7.x86_64/sources/julia-1.0.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1097
```

I am thinking this might have something to do with potentially needing a custom installation, but am not sure..

Julia session info:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.0.3
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-redhat-linux)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, sandybridge)
Environment:
  JULIA_DIR = /global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/julia/1.0.3
```

Package version in my project:

```
julia> Pkg.status()
    Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
  [e2554f3b] Clp v0.8.0
  [e2685f51] ECOS v0.11.0
  [4076af6c] JuMP v0.21.2
  [eadc2687] Pandas v1.4.0
```

Issue is posted on github here: [github.com/JuliaOpt/Clp.jl/issues/90](http://github.com/JuliaOpt/Clp.jl/issues/90)

Comment: Please link when cross-posting to avoid duplication of effort: https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Clp.jl/issues/90.

Answer (score 0):

For the above system, you need to make sure that a GNU compiler collection (gcc) is loaded onto the system before installing and building the Clp package in Julia.